# How would I write this as a recursive formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$400\cdot\left(\dfrac 13\right)^{20}+400\cdot\left(\dfrac 13\right)^{19}+400\cdot\left(\dfrac 13\right)^{18}+400\cdot\left(\dfrac 13\right)^{17}+\cdots+400\cdot \left(\dfrac 13\right)^0.$$

I can solve the problem by doing this manually but I want a sequence formula for this.

Answer (score 1):

(This answer corresponds to the [second edition](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2672946/2).)

$s_n = s_{n-1} + 400\cdot (\frac13)^{21-n}$ for $n \in \{1,\dots,20\}$, $s_0 = 0$

Comment: @AndrewLi Thanks for comment.  Fixed error.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
400 \sum_{i=1}^{21} \left( \frac{1}{3} \right)^{21-i}.
\end{eqnarray*}